# Heroku update hash signature mismatch

Tags: git, heroku

I am going to deploy a java web application to heroku.

This is my git repository in github:

[Hithub simple project](https://github.com/Sajjad-HTLO/Book-Store2)

I successfully deployed web app to heroku:

[image]

but when i want to open it, it has some internal errors:

Here is my web app heroku link:

https://book-2.herokuapp.com/

When i want to update heroku from command line, it says: `update hash signature mismatch`

[image]

What should i do?

Comment: It looks like something is corrupted in your Heroku toolbelt. It might be best to uninstall and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you a firewall may be preventing your CLI client from updating. Try following this guide to [Using an HTTP proxy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy).

Comment: The portnumber needs to be whatever you proxy port is. And that depends on your proxy, so I can't answer.